# How to calculate the total size of Blob storage containers in an storage account when using the new Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I have been using `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` for past year or two and this is how I was calculating the size of all containers:

```cs
    var myStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(myConnectionString, string.Empty));
    var myClient = myStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    var myContainers = myClient.ListContainers();

    containerSize = myContainers .Sum(container => 
      container.ListBlobs(null, true).Cast<CloudBlockBlob>().Sum(blobItem => blobItem.Properties.Length));
```

However, that package is now deprecated and I have upgraded to use `Azure.Storage.Blobs`.

I tried to use the ListContainers example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-containers-list?tabs=dotnet), but it looks like it needs C# 8:

```cs
async static Task ListContainers(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient, 
                                string prefix, 
                                int? segmentSize)
{
    string continuationToken = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        do
        {
            // Call the listing operation and enumerate the result segment.
            // When the continuation token is empty, the last segment has been returned
            // and execution can exit the loop.
            var resultSegment = 
                blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainersAsync(BlobContainerTraits.Metadata, prefix, default)
                .AsPages(continuationToken, segmentSize);
            await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobContainerItem> containerPage in resultSegment)
            {
                foreach (BlobContainerItem containerItem in containerPage.Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Container name: {0}", containerItem.Name);
                }

                // Get the continuation token and loop until it is empty.
                continuationToken = containerPage.ContinuationToken;

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        } while (continuationToken != string.Empty);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}
```

I am also not sure if looping through it is the right way to get the total size of the containers in the storage account.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, looping is the best/easy way that you have to calculate the total size of your blob container. Let me know if you need a more detailed answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a better way then looping trough blobs. I modified given by you example

wchich works in C# 8.0

```cs
async static Task<Dictionary<string, long>> ListContainers(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient,
                                        string connectionString,
                                        string prefix,
                                        int? segmentSize)
{
    string continuationToken = string.Empty;
    var sizes = new Dictionary<string, long>();
    try
    {

        do
        {
            // Call the listing operation and enumerate the result segment.
            // When the continuation token is empty, the last segment has been returned
            // and execution can exit the loop.
            var resultSegment =
                blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainersAsync(BlobContainerTraits.Metadata, prefix, default)
                .AsPages(continuationToken, segmentSize);
            await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobContainerItem> containerPage in resultSegment)
            {

                foreach (BlobContainerItem containerItem in containerPage.Values)
                {
                    BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerItem.Name);

                    var size = container.GetBlobs().Sum(b => b.Properties.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault());

                    sizes.Add(containerItem.Name, size);

                    Console.WriteLine("Container name: {0} size: {1}", containerItem.Name.PadRight(30), size);
                }

                // Get the continuation token and loop until it is empty.
                continuationToken = containerPage.ContinuationToken;

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        } while (continuationToken != string.Empty);

        return sizes;
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}
```

and this one for C# 7.x (to compile you just need the `ToListAsync()` method, which is in the `System.Linq.Async` NuGet package. )

```cs
async static Task<Dictionary<string, long>> ListContainers(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient,
                                        string connectionString,
                                        string prefix,
                                        int? segmentSize)
        {
            string continuationToken = string.Empty;
            var sizes = new Dictionary<string, long>();
            try
            {

                do
                {
                    // Call the listing operation and enumerate the result segment.
                    // When the continuation token is empty, the last segment has been returned
                    // and execution can exit the loop.
                    var resultSegment =
                        await blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainersAsync(BlobContainerTraits.Metadata, prefix, default)
                        .AsPages(continuationToken, segmentSize).ToListAsync();
                     foreach (Azure.Page<BlobContainerItem> containerPage in resultSegment)
                    {

                        foreach (BlobContainerItem containerItem in containerPage.Values)
                        {
                            BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerItem.Name);

                            var size = container.GetBlobs().Sum(b => b.Properties.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault());

                            sizes.Add(containerItem.Name, size);

                            Console.WriteLine("Container name: {0} size: {1}", containerItem.Name.PadRight(30), size);
                        }

                        // Get the continuation token and loop until it is empty.
                        continuationToken = containerPage.ContinuationToken;

                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }

                } while (continuationToken != string.Empty);

                return sizes;
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I just ran this code for .NET 4.8 using these packages:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Azure.Core" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Azure.Storage.Blobs" version="12.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Azure.Storage.Common" version="12.5.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Async" version="4.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encodings.Web" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Text.Json" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

and all was fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and also sorry, I should have been more precise. It is the wait foreach (Azure.Page<BlobContainerItem> containerPage in resultSegment) that tells me I need C# 8.

Comment: Thanks again but still having problem. The ToListAsync and Azure.Page<BlobContainerItem> has red squiggly line under them saying they can not be found. My .net framework for my project is 4.8.

Comment: I ran it for .NET 4.8 without any issue.

Comment: Very strange. I have all those packages and my versions are either equal or a bit higher. I even checked my default C# using csc -langversion:? command and it tells me I am using C# 8. The error keeps saying are you missing an assembly reference or a Using statement for that ToListAsync. Totally bamboozled. :)

Comment: Did you try creating totally new project? Did you clean your solution? I run above snippets for dotnet core 3.1 (C#), and dotnet core 2.x and dotnet framework 4.8 (C# 7.x) withot any issue.

Comment: Yes I tried all that. I have a new project with the same problem. I have latest updates of Windows, .Net, all of its libraries. I believe your answer should solve the problem. So I mark your answer as a solution and post a separate question about the error. Thank you so much for helping out.